# Sending 32bit integer from python script to arduino via serial for use in driving RGB strip

Tags: python, arduino

first post so go easy on me.

I have made a python script which takes a screenshot of the current display and finds the most frequently reappearing RGB colour value.

I am attempting to send this to via serial to an arduino pro micro (with some supplementary components)  to drive a 12v LED strip.

I am bit-shifting the individual red, green and blue values, and am adding them together into an unsigned 32 bit integer to be send to the arduino which will then use a bitmask to then get the original values back using PWM pins on the arduino control three MOSFETS (N-Channel) to drive the individual colours on the RGB strip. Each colour has 256 values so can be represented in 8bits seen below.

32bit unsigned int

un-used  blue     green    red

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

red mask

00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111

green mask

00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000

blue mask

00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000

My issue is that the serial communication between the python script and the arduino doesn't appear to be working, and I cannot figure out why. Is it something to do with the format of the unsigned 32 bit integer I'm sending? I'm not really finding any information on the acceptable formats and have little experience using serial communications.

What I do know is that the arduino circuit is definitely connected correctly as I can fully drive the RGB strip by specifying values on the arduino side.

The python script is definitely connecting to the arduino as I am connecting using hardware information found in windows device manager when the arduino is connected, and while the script is running I cannot use anything else to connect to the COM port used by the arduino.

The python script is calculating and formatting the values as I intend as I can simply print them to console instead of writing to serial to confirm.

````
from PIL import Image
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time
from collections import Counter

if __name__ == '__main__': ###main program###

    # open comms with arduino
    VID = "2341" #arduino pro micro HEX vendor ID given throught the arduino IDE
    PID = "8037" #arduino pro micro HEX product ID given throught the arduino IDE
    arduino_pro_micro_port = None
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports()) #get ports information

    for port in ports:
        if PID and VID in port.hwid: #look for matching PID and VID
            arduino_pro_micro_port = port.device #serial port of arduino nano pro

    if arduino_pro_micro_port == None:
        print("Couldn't find an ardiuno pro micro to communicate with")
    else:
        COMPort = serial.Serial(arduino_pro_micro_port, 115200, writeTimeout = 0) #open connection for RGB values to be written

        while True: #loop forever
            image = ImageGrab.grab() #grab screenshot
            image = image.resize((512, 288)) #20% size for faster processing
            image = image.load() #load image so pixel information can be interrogated

            RGBlist = []

            #seperate pixel tuple into lists for red, green  and blue
            for horizontal in range(0, 512, 1): #for all horizontal pixels
                for vertical in range(0, 288, 1): #for all vertical pixels

                    red = image[horizontal, vertical][0]
                    blue = image[horizontal, vertical][1] << 8
                    green = image[horizontal, vertical][2] << 16
                    RGBlist.append(red + green + blue)

            sendLong = Counter(RGBlist).most_common(1)
            print("send " + str(sendLong[0][0]))
            COMPort.write(sendLong[0][0]) #write RGB to serial port
            print("reci "+ str(COMPort.readline())) #read and print line from arduino
            time.sleep(0.1) #wait 0.1 seconds
```end of python code



```arduino code

//set pin integers for RGB
int LEDRPin = 5;
int LEDGPin = 6;
int LEDBPin = 9;

//setup variable store for RGB values
unsigned long incomingLong = 0; //store the incomoing byte for processing#

unsigned long redMask = 255; //bitmask for red value
unsigned long greenMask = 65280; //bitmask for green value
unsigned long blueMask = 16711680; //bitmask for blue value

unsigned long Rv = 0; //red value will be stored here
unsigned long Gv = 0; //green value will be stored here
unsigned long Bv = 0; //blue value will be stored here

unsigned long SAVE_Rv = 0; //red value will be saved here
unsigned long SAVE_Gv = 0; //green value will be saved here
unsigned long SAVE_Bv = 0; //blue value will be saved here

void setup() {
  //initialise RBG pins as outputs
  pinMode(LEDRPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDGPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDBPin, OUTPUT);

  //start serial comms
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if(Serial.available())// only send data back if data has been sent
  {
    incomingLong = Serial.read(); //read RGB values from serial port
    Serial.write("Ready");
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(300);
  if(Serial.available() >= 0) // only send data back if data has been sent
  {
    incomingLong = Serial.read(); //read RGB values from serial port
    Serial.write(incomingLong);

    Rv = redMask & incomingLong; //get red value
    Gv = greenMask & incomingLong; //get green value
    Bv = blueMask & incomingLong; //get blue value

    Rv = Rv >> 0; //shift to LSB
    Gv = Gv >> 8; //shift to LSB
    Bv = Bv >> 16; //shift to LSB

    Rv = (int) Rv; //Cast to int
    Gv = (int) Gv; //Cast to int
    Bv = (int) Bv; //Cast to int

    analogWrite(LEDRPin, Rv); //write red value to output pin
    analogWrite(LEDGPin, Gv); //write green value to output pin
    analogWrite(LEDBPin, Bv); //write blue value to output pin

    SAVE_Rv = Rv;
    SAVE_Gv = Gv;
    SAVE_Bv = Bv;
  }
}

```end of arduino code
````

Comment: Okay, Let's start small. send some test value from your python code and write the value back from arduino (which I see you are already doing). So, now read the COM port on your python code to see if you get your test values back correctly. I'll try to help you throughout the way.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the response Faisal. I have stripped similar code back to be simpler in that I after finding and connecting to the arduino in python, I am just writing 255 and 0 with a three second interval between them. I've got the arduino just listening and printing back what it is reading.

Comment: Using Serial.write(var) doesn't return anything to console but Serial.println(var) does. The strange behaviour is that for the first couple of minutes of writing and reading, 255 gets returned as b'4294967295\r\n', and 0 gets returned as b'0\r\n'. After, everything returns as b'0\r\n'. Do you have any idea why? This is repeatable as long as I stop the python script, disconnect and reconnect the arduino.

Comment: Please checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written and tested my watered down communication solution for your case on python27 and arduino Uno but should give you more or less the same results. Test it and let me know if you need clarification or get stuck at some point.

```
# python27

import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import struct
import sys

arduino_pro_micro_port = 'COM3'
COMPort = serial.Serial(arduino_pro_micro_port, 115200, writeTimeout = 0)

while True:
    r = 12
    g = 145
    b = 87
    if COMPort.in_waiting:
        #COMPort.write(struct.pack("l", 123)) # sending one long directly
        COMPort.write(struct.pack("BBB", r, g, b)) # B means unsigned byte 
        print COMPort.readline()
```

```
// Arduino

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //start serial comms
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void loop() {
  // I'm taking the delay off as that might cause synchronization issues on the receiver side

  while (Serial.available() <= 3); // only send data back if data has been sent
  int r = Serial.read(); //read RGB values from serial port
  int g = Serial.read(); //read RGB values from serial port
  int b = Serial.read(); //read RGB values from serial port
  Serial.println("RGB: ");
  Serial.println(r);
  Serial.println(g);
  Serial.println(b);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, very much appreciate this. Your code does work as expected if I change the "<" to "<=" in the while Serial.available line. I've altered it, adding little bits of functionality back in and I think using bitshifts is what is causing the issue with my original code. Shifting and sending, then unshifting and sending back yield values that don't agree. I didn't realise that struct.pack was a thing so I guess I'll use that and I can just send as integers.

p.s I have voted your answer up, but because I'm new here it is not public. I do really appreciate the help. I've got it from here :)

Comment: Hi again, Yes you are right about the <= thing. So, I've edited it. And please mark my answer as the accepted one if you believe it helped you. Thank you.